# Optimal Speed for Travel Accounting for Time Dilation

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics

I am wondering if there is a velocity such that going any faster would lead to me arriving at a destination later from the perspective of those at the specified destination. I tried solving this by taking the derivative $\frac{dt'}{dv}$ (I use $t'$ for time observed by others) of $t'=t\gamma=\frac{d}{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^c}}}$ and then solving for when $\frac{dt'}{dv}=0$, but my physics teacher said that this is wrong because velocity is dependent on time, or something of that ilk. Does anyone have an explanation for this? I have seen other discussions online, but they seem to be more based on heuristics than the actual calculations, so an answer that shows the math would be helpful.

Thank you to anyone who answers!

Comment: Which reference frame is $d$ measured in?  I suspect this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: *"I am wondering if there is a velocity such that going any faster would lead to me arriving at a destination later from the perspective of those at the specified destination."* No. There is not.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! That's what I heard online, but I am interested in a more mathematical proof rather a heuristic one because I feel that the mathematics allow for a deeper understanding of the problem, so I was just wondering if someone could explain the actual derivation of that result.